# html slider on change event -- error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the value of slider in the span "sliderInput".

But i am getting error cannot set property 'innerHTML' of NULL.

Alert takes place but rest all three statements fails in the onchange handler.

Html code :---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tt.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="doc_onload()">

<p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

            <input id="HeaterSlider" class="img_slider_center" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="0"  list=volsettings>
            <datalist id=volsettings>
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            </datalist>
            <span type="text" id="sliderInputTxt" style=" color:#DDDFED">Heater Value : </span>
            <span type="text" id="sliderInput" style=" color:#DDDFED">0</span>


</body>
</html>
```

javascript :--

```
function vscpws_slider(     sliderCanvasName,    // Where it should be placed
                            slideTxtname
                               )
{

    this.sliderCanvas = document.getElementById(sliderCanvasName);
    this.sliderTxtcanvas = document.getElementById(slideTxtname);


    this.sliderTxtcanvasId = slideTxtname;
    this.sliderCanvas.onchange = this.updateSlider.bind(this);

}


vscpws_slider.prototype.updateSlider = function()
{
            alert("hell0");

            //this.slidertxtCanvas.innerHTML = this.sliderCanvas.value;
            //document.getElementById(this.sliderTxtCanvasId).textContent = this.sliderCanvas.value;
            document.getElementById(this.sliderTxtCanvasId).innerHTML = this.sliderCanvas.value;
}


function doc_onload()
{
    var btn = new vscpws_slider('HeaterSlider',
                                'sliderInput');
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.sliderTxtcanvasId` instead of `this.sliderTxtCanvasId`? JavaScript is **case-sensitive**

Answer (score 0):

As  **putvande** said, javascript is case sensitive, so you should use `this.sliderTxtcanvasId`, not `this.sliderTxtCanvasId`

```
vscpws_slider.prototype.updateSlider = function(){
    document.getElementById(this.sliderTxtcanvasId).innerHTML = this.sliderCanvas.value;
//--shouldn't be capital C but small------^
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ass5dapj/)